# Docker Exec with OpenSSL and stdin, stdout

Tags: docker, openssl, pipe

I'm trying to use docker exec with OpenSSL and piping like this. I have a container thats running called test1.

```
1. openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:123 2048 | docker exec -i test1 sh -c 'cat >/key.pem
2. docker exec test1 cat key.pem
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
    DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,DE60A9F33B9E508D

    /uJYBfM6YwCkIgrgQSH......
3. docker exec test1 cat key.pem | openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key -out client.csr -passin pass:123

write /dev/stdout: broken pipe
```

If I run these commands without using docker they work OK. Is/does docker do anything different with the stdin and stdout streams ?

Comment: your last `docker exec` has neither `-i` nor `-t` can you try with `-it` ?

Comment: Just tried this same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by doing two things:

1. Make the output line buffered as suggested above, meaning the docker command becomes `docker exec -t test1 cat key.pem`
2. The way you are running things right now, it is not really clear where the docker exec arguments end and where the redirection via the `|` starts. Simply change the overall command to something that makes this clear to bash, this should work

`docker exec -t test1 cat key.pem | openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key /dev/stdin -passin pass:123`

Comment: Thanks for this. So a bit of progress if I run the above I get and unknown option `unknown option client.csr` which is a bit strange because I know the string works without docker exec.

Comment: made a small edit also grouping the right hand side of the piping, should help I think :)

Comment: OK so this works `docker exec -t test1 cat key.pem | openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key /dev/stdin -passin pass:123`